# Something strange happening with JPanel and java g.fillOval() method

Tags: java, graphics, colors, jpanel

I am using Graphics to draw ovals on a JPanel. Something is happening with the lowest oval, which, instead of staying one colour, is multiple colours in stripes across the oval. This doesn't happen with the other ovals.

My JFrame size is 600 by 600.
Here is my code:

```
package virus;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class VirusGamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Random colour = new Random();
    int score = 0;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString("Score: "+ score,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawOval(200,150,200,200);
        Color rand = new Color(colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255));
        g.setColor(rand);
        g.fillOval(270,50,50,50);
        g.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
        g.fillOval(450,100,50,50);//this line is causing the problem
        g.fillOval(100,400,50,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never override `paint(...)`, for a **JPanel/JComponent** for such a small thing. Always override `paintComponent(...)` for this thingy :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a small test program that draws your panel in a JFrame and everything looks fine for me (I have no stripes). I'm using Java 7. Maybe your error is in an other part of your program :).

Do you get the same error with this program?

```
import javax.swing.*;    
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class VirusGamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Random colour = new Random();
    int score = 0;

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.drawString("Score: "+ score,200,200);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.drawOval(200,150,200,200);
        Color rand = new Color(colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255),colour.nextInt(255));
        g.setColor(rand);
        g.fillOval(270,50,50,50);
        g.fillOval(100,100,50,50);
        g.fillOval(450,100,50,50);//this line is causing the problem
        g.fillOval(100,400,50,50);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setSize(600,600);
        f.add(new VirusGamePanel());
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the error with this program either - but the program I wrote adds the JPanel from an external file (so it makes the JFrame, then adds the panel in the constructor method). Could this be the problem? Thanks for the help! :)